# How to replace repeating entries in a data frame with n-(number of times it's repeated) in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by

In my data I have repeating entries in a column. What I'm trying to do is if an entry *n* is repeated more than 2 times within a column, then I want to replace that entry with *`n-(number_of_times_it_has_repeated - 2)`*. For example, if my data looks like this:

```
  df <- data.frame(
  A = c(1,2,2,4,5,7,7,7,7,2,8,8),
  B = c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13)
)
> df
A  B
1  2
2  3
2  4
4  5
5  6
7  7
7  8
7  9
7 10
2 11
8 12
8 13
```

we can see that in `df$A` 7 is repeated 4 times. If the entry is repeated more than 2 times, then I want to replace that entry. So in my example,the 1st and 2nd entry of the number 7 would remain unchanged. The 3rd instance of the number 7 would be replaced by : *7 - (3-2)*. The 4th instance of number 7 would be replaced by *7 - (4-2)*.

We can also see that in `df$A`, the number 2 is repeated 3 times. using the same method, the 3rd instance of number 2 would be replaced with *2 - (3-2)*.

As there are no repeating values in `df$B`, that column would remain unchanged.

For clarity, my expected result would be:

```
dfNew <- data.frame(
  A = c(1,2,2,4,5,7,7,6,5,1,8,8),
  B = c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13)
)
> dfNew
A  B
1  2
2  3
2  4
4  5
5  6
7  7
7  8
6  9
5 10
1 11
8 12
8 13
```

Comment: The third occurrence of 2 in `df$A` is to replaced with (2 minus (3 minus 2)). That is,  2 - (3-2) = 2-1 = 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can do it for one column -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  transmute(A =  A - c(rep(0, 2), row_number())[row_number()]) %>%
  ungroup

#       A
#   <dbl>
# 1     1
# 2     2
# 3     2
# 4     4
# 5     5
# 6     7
# 7     7
# 8     6
# 9     5
#10     1
#11     8
#12     8
```

To do it for all the columns you can use `map_dfc` -

```
purrr::map_dfc(names(df), ~{
  df %>%
    group_by(.data[[.x]]) %>%
    transmute(!!.x :=  .data[[.x]] - c(rep(0, 2), row_number())[row_number()])%>%
    ungroup
})

#       A     B
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     2
# 2     2     3
# 3     2     4
# 4     4     5
# 5     5     6
# 6     7     7
# 7     7     8
# 8     6     9
# 9     5    10
#10     1    11
#11     8    12
#12     8    13
```

The logic here is that for each number we subtract 0 from first 2 values and later we subtract `-1`, `-2` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the order if you don't want it here is my approach, if you have some data where after the changes there are still some duplicates then i can work on the answer to put it in a function or something.

```
my_df <- data.frame(A = c(1,2,2,4,5,7,7,7,7,2,8,8),
                B = c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

my_df <- my_df[order(my_df$A, my_df$B),]

my_df$Id <- seq.int(from = 1, to = nrow(my_df), by = 1)

my_temp <- my_df %>% group_by(A) %>% filter(n() > 2) %>% mutate(Count = seq.int(from = 1, to = n(), by = 1)) %>% filter(Count > 2) %>% mutate(A = A - (Count - 2))

my_var <- which(my_df$Id %in% my_temp$Id)
if (length(my_var)) {
  my_df <- my_df[-my_var,]
  my_df <- rbind(my_df, my_temp[, c("A", "B", "Id")])
}
my_df <- my_df[order(my_df$A, my_df$B),]
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option using `ave` + `pmax` + `seq_along`

```
list2DF(
  lapply(
    df,
    function(x) {
      x - ave(x, x, FUN = function(v) pmax(seq_along(v) - 2, 0))
    }
  )
)
```

gives

```
   A  B
1  1  2
2  2  3
3  2  4
4  4  5
5  5  6
6  7  7
7  7  8
8  6  9
9  5 10
10 1 11
11 8 12
12 8 13
```